# hashing ids to store efficiently in redis

Tags: python, redis

I am using `redis-py` to store some data on redis. I have two lists, one is a list of `userids` and second is a list of `foodids`, elements in both lists are of int type. And for each pair of `clientid` and `foodid`, I have a `recommendation`, which is a float. So basically, I have a `recommendation` for each pair of `clientid` and `foodid` which I am trying to store in `redis`.

I have experimented with both `HSET` and `SET` to store the data. With `SET`, I create the key by storing `clientid` and `foodid` as 32 bit numbers in a 64 bit number by left shifting `foodid`. With `HSET`, I join `clientid` and `foodid` (convert to string -> join two numbers -> convert back to int) and then floor divide by `400` to create a master key. Inside the master key, I add the key, which is concatenation of `clientid` and `foodid` and it's value as `recommendation`.

I get promising results with `HSET` for small number of keys (~100k) (almost half of `SET`) but when I try to store million of keys `SET` is performing better.

I have two questions:

1. Why `HSET` is performing poorly then `SET`. My hypothesis for why this is happening is `HSET` has more overhead than `SET`. With higher number of keys in a bucket, `HSET` optimises this overhead. In my case, I was only storing 3-4 keys in a bucket instead of 400
2. What would be a better way to create master keys, such that I am able to store at least 400 keys within a bucket, but also able to retrieve the `recommendation` with just using `clientid` and `foodid`.